# Обновление виджета

Tags: android, виджет, android-widgets

Есть виджет, который отсчитывает часы до определенного события, и, скажем, есть некая функция `abcd()`, которая рассчитывает время и выводит на виджет.

Проблема в том, что, чтобы он показал актуальное количество часов, надо его удалить и снова добавить на рабочий стол. Как сделать чтобы он сам обновлялся?

`Updatepriodmills` вроде выставил на полчаса, `abcd()` находится в методе `onUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, никакой хитрости нет.
Просто вызываешь функцию в методе onUpdate класса AppWidgetProvider.
У меня это делается так:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
        myUpdate(context, metrics, id);         
    }
}
```

в xml задаем параметры обновления в милисекундах

```
  android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
```

в принципе есть еще вариант обновления виджета с помощью AlarmManager
вот код на обновление всех виджетов через заданный интервал времени (в примере выставлено гарантированное обновление раз в 2 часа):

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // create some random data

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), Reminderwidget4x1.class);
        int[] allCurrentWidget = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetID : allCurrentWidget) {
            Reminderwidget4x1.myUpdate(this, metrics, widgetID);
        }

        thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), ReminderWidget4x4.class);
        allCurrentWidget = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetID : allCurrentWidget) {
            ReminderWidget4x4.myUpdate(this, appWidgetManager, widgetID);
        }

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(allCurrentWidget, R.id.widget4x4List);

        stopSelf();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public static void startUpdateAlarm(Context cc) {

        int intervalInMillis = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        Intent intent = new Intent(cc, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(cc, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,1000*2);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) cc.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), intervalInMillis, pintent);
    }
}
```